# Difficulties with using Windows GDI Print API

Tags: printing, gdi

I have programmed printing using GDI Print API Windows.
The program is in FreePascal (Lazarus development environment), the sequence of calls to the Windows API functions is as follows (I've omitted details like variable values for brevity, they don't seem to affect my problem):

```
PrintDlgW(@lppd);
GlobalLock(lppd.hDevMode);   
GlobalLock(lppd.hDevNames); 
SetAbortProc(lppd.hdc,@PrintAbortProcCallback);
StartDocW(lppd.hdc,@docinfo);
StartPage(lppd.hdc);
TextOutW( *... print something ...* );
EndPage(lppd.hdc);
EndDoc(lppd.hdc);
GlobalUnlock(lppd.hDevMode);
GlobalUnlock(lppd.hDevNames);
GlobalFree(lppd.hDevMode);
GlobalFree(lppd.hDevNames);
```

Seemingly everything works as it should, but only on the first pass. When I start printing again, the system probably waits for freeing some resource (I have no idea what) and the program stops on the call of PrintDlgW. Only when I force terminate my program (from the debugger) does a new Print Dialog open. Could anyone think what I forgot to release or where I am making a mistake, please?

I have tried checking the return codes of all functions, but none of them report an error. I have tried releasing the printer device context (DeleteDC) at the end but it has no effect.
I would need to find out what source I am forgetting to release, or if my printing procedure is completely wrong and needs to be reworked.